# SOLVED: What is the distribution of the squared exponential of two gaussian distributions of odd dimension?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Let $X,X'$ follow the $n$ dimensional Gaussian distribution (zero mean unit variance for simplicity).  My question is: what is the distribution of $Y = e^{-\|X-X'\|^2}$, particuarly when $n$ is odd?

**$n$ even case**: I believe I know the answer for $n$ even.  We know (or at least I think I know) that $Z = \|X-X'\|^2 \sim \chi^2 (n)$, which has density:
$$\rho_Z (z) = \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} z^{\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{z}{2}}$$
The density of $Y$ will therefore be:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\rho_Y (y) &= \frac{dz}{dy} \rho_Z (z) \\
&= \frac{dz}{dy} \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} z^{\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{z}{2}}
\end{array}$$
where $y = e^{-z}$, so $z = -\log(y)$, and:
$$\begin{array}{rl} \rho_Y (y) &= -\frac{d \log(y)}{dy} \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} (-1)^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \log(y)^{\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{\frac{\log(y)}{2}} \\
 &= (-1)^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} \sqrt{\frac{\log(y)^{n-2}}{y}} \end{array}$$

**$n$ odd case**: <s>the above derivation fails as the density becomes complex, so I'm wondering if anyone could suggest a way forward?  Or is the density simply ill-defined for $n$ odd?</s> (see below)

(the closest answer I found was [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281934/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-exponential-of-a-chi-square-variable), but this only helps for $e^{\|X-X'\|^2}$, not (at least as far as I can tell) for $e^{-\|X-X'\|^2}$).

PS: also, does this distribution have a name?

**UPDATE:** as noted by whuber, I forgot to take the absolute value of the Jacobian.  Also note that $y \in (0,1]$, so $(-\log (y))^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$ is well defined.  Corrected derivation is:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\rho_Y (y) &= \left| \frac{dz}{dy} \right| \rho_Z (z) \\
&= \left| \frac{dz}{dy} \right| \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} z^{\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{z}{2}} \\
&= \left| \frac{d \log(y)}{dy} \right| \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} (-\log(y))^{\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{\frac{\log(y)}{2}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2^{n/2} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2})} \sqrt{\frac{(-\log(y))^{n-2}}{y}} \end{array}$$

Comment: There's nothing special about odd $n:$ you simply forgot to take the absolute value of the Jacobian.

Comment: d'oh - thanks.  Also I was forgetting that $y \in (0,1]$ here.  I'll update the question.  I'm still a little curious if this distribution has a name as it seems to pop up all over the place in machine learning when you start looking (eg think of the gram matrix of an SVM - or any kernel-based method - using and RBF kernel where the inputs are drawn from a Gaussian distribution).